# how to tackle Matlab error in calculation of exp?

Tags: matlab, precision, exp

I have to calculate the angle of complex summations like

```
(exp(1i*0)+exp(1i*2*pi/3)+exp(1i*-2*pi/3))
```

which is equal to

```
(exp(1i*0)+exp(1i*2*pi/3)+exp(1i*4*pi/3))
```

but the results are different! because of the precision of exp matlab function.

```
ans =

   4.4409e-16


ans =

  -2.2204e-16 + 2.2204e-16i
```

the angle of the first one is zero but the second one result $3\pi/4$ which is wrong!

Comment: Use `vpa` if you have the symbolic math toolbox: `vpa('(exp(i*0)+exp(i*2*pi/3)+exp(i*4*pi/3))')` is exactly 0.

Comment: `2.2204e-16` is the definition of `eps` in MATLAB. You might as well consider it to be 0.  This is not an error.  This is due to floating-point precision when evaluating functions whose output is "supposed" to be 0.

Comment: You could also consider to decompose your calculation to ```theta = (0 + 2/3 + 4/3)*pi; res = sin( theta )+1i*cos( theta );``` to reduce floating point errors. [Or even ```theta = (0 + 2 + 4)*pi/3;```]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format